# How to listen for specific property changes in Redux store after an action is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am currently trying to conceptualize how to handle dispatching an action in a component based on a data change after a dispatch in another component.

Take this scenario:

`dispatch(someAjax)` -> property in state updates.

After this, I need another component dependent on this same property to know that is has updated and dispatch an action based on the new value.

Rather than using some type of `value.on(change...` solution, what is the preferred way to handle this type of action 'cascading'?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two basic approaches: either a middleware that diffs the state after an action is done, or using Redux's low-level `store.subscribe` API.

The Redux FAQ has [an answer that covers this](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#how-do-i-subscribe-to-only-a-portion-of-the-state-can-i-get-the-dispatched-action-as-part-of-the-subscription).  Also, I keep a categorized list of Redux-related addons and utilities, and that includes a group of [existing store change subscription libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions) that implement various approaches to listening for data changes.

Comment: Thanks for that list, it's really helpful. What I am actually trying to figure out is the best way to inform several components that some data is back from an AJAX call and that X key has changed. Each of these components would then possibly fire their own actions. I can get at the changes in middleware, but the part I am trying to figure out is what to do when the change is detected. I feel like some sort of event bus is needed, but that doesn't feel right with Redux. Any advice there?

Comment: The primary recommended approach for communication in React and Redux is parents passing props to children, and children running callbacks to notify parents.  However, other approaches like event buses certainly have their uses, and if an event bus fits your use case, go for it.  You may want to look at http://ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/ and http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/ for examples.

Comment: Although you didn't specifically answer the question, the first item on your list did work for my case. redux-watch is a simple and creative way to get this functionality. Thanks again for the list, it is helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I recently split the FAQ page into separate pages per category.  Just updated the link in my answer to match.  Thanks!

Answer (score 108):

You may use Redux's `mapStateToProps` and `connect` with React's `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` hook.

So basically your code could look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ 
   specificProperty: state.specificProperty,
   // any props you need else
});

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      // render your component  
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (prevProps.specificProperty !== this.props.specificProperty) {
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }
}

YourComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Fits the provided tags, then

Comment: Nice. Also, possible typo? Do you mean `nextProps.specificProperty !== this.props.specificProperty`?

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal, if you don't use react there's probably a better option, depending on your JS Framework, than redux ;)

Comment: Minor update to this, `componentWillUpdate` should no longer be used with React 16. [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) is now the recommended approach.

Comment: Depends - could be `getDerivedStateFromProps` if you want new state, but could be you want to use `componentDidUpdate` for a bit more versatility.

Comment: I used this approach and worked for me like a charm

Comment: "You may use Redux's mapStateToProps" - this is incorrect: `mapStateToProps` is in Redux-React, not `redux.js` - remember you can use Redux without using React, and if you're using Redux without React then you don't get `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: This approach worked great for me too. To use with functional components, I changed componentDidUpdate to `useEffect(() => { /* Do whatever you want */ }, [props.specificProperty])`  with mapStateToProps defined as an interface and set as my component props